# POST request with basic auth not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, basic-authentication

I am trying to perform a POST request with basic authentication to get an access token from an api.
I have to pass grant_type and a code that I request before that in the body of the request and basic auth with username and password in the header.The whole request has to be x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 encoded.

It seems like I'm out of my depth here as I keep getting bad request errors.

This is the relevant part of the code

```
  var code_cont = examplecode;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://example.com',
        data: {"grant_type":'authorization_code', 'code': code_cont},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        beforeSend : function(req) {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic username:password');
        },
  });
```

For username and password I inserted the relevant information.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can trap the Ajax call as you are using jQuery and add the appropriate base64 encoding.

`beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
};`

Note - for security reasons (it is trivial to decode the header and steal the password and username) you should use SSL or some other form of encryption between the user and the server.